# Memory error elbow curve

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, k-means

l executed a k-means clustring and when l did visualization using elbow curve l got a memory error which is associated whith the above line code :

```
tss = np.sum(pdist(patches)**2)/patches.shape[0]
```

How can l fix that ?

```
 K= range(50,100,10) 
# Total with-in sum of square
    wcss = [sum(d**2) for d in dist]
    tss = np.(pdist(patches)**2)/patches.shape[0]
    bss = tss-wcss
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(K, bss/tss*100, 'b*-')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
    plt.ylabel('Percentage of variance explained')
    plt.title('Elbow for KMeans clustering')
    plt.show()
```

l got a memory error

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-73c7d61897f4> in <module>()
      1 # Total with-in sum of square
      2 wcss = [sum(d**2) for d in dist]
----> 3 tss = np.sum(pdist(patches)**2)/patches.shape[0]
      4 bss = tss-wcss
      5 fig = plt.figure()

/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.pyc in pdist(X, metric, p, w, V, VI)
   1218 
   1219     m, n = s
-> 1220     dm = np.zeros((m * (m - 1)) // 2, dtype=np.double)
   1221 
   1222     wmink_names = ['wminkowski', 'wmi', 'wm', 'wpnorm']

MemoryError:
```

Comment: What is `patches.shape`?  In the error, `m` is `patches.shape[0]`.

Comment: patches.shape[0] is my data =  250000

Comment: patches.shape= (250000,108)

Comment: A (250000, 249999) array is too big.

Comment: so what would be the appropriate value ?